# Is there a way to know why Kivy apk app doesn't work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash, kivy

I've spent ten weeks working on a Kivy app and now the APK file for android won't work, and I don't have a way to know what the hell is the issue. Is there a way to know why the hell it crashes? I'm trying to open it with BlueStacks and just flashes for a second. Works fine when running from pycharm.

Edit: Buildozer has a feature called catlog to debug: https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: Are you using `buildozer`?

Comment: yeah, seems like it has a feature called catlog, I'll give it a shot.